# src\App.js Line 124:16: 'App' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

Working on an assignment for school - I am fairly new at this.  Here is the assignemnt:
Build a static UI React ToDo application with this funcunality:

Display initial todos.
Add new todos.
Mark a todo as “completed”
Remove a todo.
The ToDo application will be initially loaded with a couple todos. The input field will allow the user to add a new todo.

When a new todo is added, a checkbox will appear to the left with a blue color to indicate it is awaiting completion. When a todo has been completed, a user can click the check mark and it will become red and the text will have strike-through, indicating it has been completed.

An X will appear to the far right allowing a todo to be removed.

I am getting an error when running my code and I cant seem to figure out how to fix this.
Here is the error I get:

src\App.js
Line 124:16:  'App' is not defined  no-undef

Here is my code.

```
App.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


var todoItems = [];
todoItems.push({ index: 1, value: "learn react", done: false });
todoItems.push({ index: 2, value: "Go shopping", done: true });
todoItems.push({ index: 3, value: "buy flowers", done: true });

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var items = this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <TodoListItem key={index} item={item} index={index} removeItem={this.props.removeItem} markTodoDone={this.props.markTodoDone} />
            );
        });
        return (
            <ul className="list-group"> {items} </ul>
        );
    }
}

class TodoListItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClickClose = this.onClickClose.bind(this);
        this.onClickDone = this.onClickDone.bind(this);
    }
    onClickClose() {
        var index = parseInt(this.props.index);
        this.props.removeItem(index);
    }
    onClickDone() {
        var index = parseInt(this.props.index);
        this.props.markTodoDone(index);
    }
    render() {
        var todoClass = this.props.item.done ?
            "done" : "undone";
        return (
            <li className="list-group-item ">
                <div className={todoClass}>
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.onClickDone}></span>
                    {this.props.item.value}
                    <button type="button" className="close" onClick={this.onClickClose}>&times;</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

class TodoForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.itemName.focus();
    }
    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newItemValue = this.refs.itemName.value;

        if (newItemValue) {
            this.props.addItem({ newItemValue });
            this.refs.form.reset();
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form ref="form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="form-inline">
                <input type="text" ref="itemName" className="form-control" placeholder="add a new todo..." />
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

class TodoHeader extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Todo list</h1>;
    }
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
        this.markTodoDone = this.markTodoDone.bind(this);
        this.state = { todoItems: todoItems };
    }
    addItem(todoItem) {
        todoItems.unshift({
            index: todoItems.length + 1,
            value: todoItem.newItemValue,
            done: false
        });
        this.setState({ todoItems: todoItems });
    }
    removeItem(itemIndex) {
        todoItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        this.setState({ todoItems: todoItems });
    }
    markTodoDone(itemIndex) {
        var todo = todoItems[itemIndex];
        todoItems.splice(itemIndex, 1);
        todo.done = !todo.done;
        todo.done ? todoItems.push(todo) : todoItems.unshift(todo);
        this.setState({ todoItems: todoItems });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="main">
                <TodoHeader />
                <TodoList items={this.props.initItems} removeItem={this.removeItem} markTodoDone={this.markTodoDone} />
                <TodoForm addItem={this.addItem} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp initItems={todoItems} />, document.getElementById('app'));
export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


const DATA = [
  { id: "todo-0", name: "Eat", completed: true },
  { id: "todo-1", name: "Sleep", completed: false },
  { id: "todo-2", name: "Repeat", completed: false }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App tasks={DATA} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any help with this error is appreciated.

Comment: You've not declared any `App` component to export into the index.js file. You also seem to be attempting to render `TodoApp` into an element with `id="app` that may or may not exist. Perhaps you meant to default export `TodoApp` and import into index.js to be rendered into the `id='root'` element. FYI, you'll want to ***not*** use the array index as the React key since React reconciliation will fail when you start removing todo's from the middle of your list or if you add sorting functionality.

Comment: Thanks - easy fix now I get this error: src\App.js
  Line 123:1:  'ReactDOM' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: You probably don't need to import and use `ReactDOM` in `App` since you should be using it in index.js.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, so would I remove this line:   ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp initItems={todoItems} />, document.getElementById('app'));  from my app.js only?

Comment: Correct. You very likely only need to render one React app into your HTML. Just ensure you are importing the correct React component into index.js and rendering that via `ReactDOM.render`.

Comment: I removed that and ran it  and now I get this error: Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
▶ 10 stack frames were collapsed.

Comment: Have you checked your index.html to ensure you've an element with the correct `id` attribute? Typically in React it's a `div` element with `id="root"`, but it can use any `id` value.

Comment: my index.html file just reads this:  <div id="app"></div>

Comment: Seems you should just move `ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp initItems={todoItems} />, document.getElementById('app'));` from `App` into index.js, and default import `TodoApp`.

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere.  I moved the ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp initItems={todoItems} />, document.getElementById('app')); into the index.js  and now i get this error: src\index.js
  Line 19:18:  'TodoApp' is not defined    react/jsx-no-undef
  Line 19:37:  'todoItems' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 0):

It's true, you haven't defined `App` in the line `export default App;`

You probably want it to be

`export default TodoApp;`

Comment: ah that was an easy fix.  Now I get this error: src\App.js
  Line 123:1:  'ReactDOM' is not defined  no-undef